# Communication of a python parent process and a python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I have only recently started working with the subprocess-module, so i  am sure, this is a rookie-question:

I am trying to start a python-subprocess from a python 3.5.2. parent script and retrieve information from it:

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(
    'C:\\IDLEX (Python GUI).exe',
    shell  = True,
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
    )

while True:
    lines = process.stdout.readlines()
    for line in lines:
            print (line)
```

What command do i have to give in the child-process to generate an output in the parent process?

I already tried `print('something')` and `sys.stdout.write('something else')` (coupled with `sys.stdout.flush()`) but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

The subprocess is running and its output is already directed to the parent process. There is no output generated because of `'C:\\IDLEX (Python GUI).exe'` does not flush anything to `stdout`.

Your script is working:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(
    'echo Hello World', # or change to any other executable or script to test
    shell  = True,
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
)
```

Output:

```
Hello World
```

You may try to run `C:\\IDLEX (Python GUI).exe` directly in the cmd to check.